# How does stat growth work in Final Fantasy (for NES)?

Tags: final-fantasy

Take a look at this picture:

[image]

(from the [gamercorner](https://guides.gamercorner.net/) website)

What do the `A B C D E F` letters mean? I'm assuming there is a value attached to each, like maybe `A` means `+6` per level up, but I haven't been able to find anything yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stats in the original Final Fantasy for the NES have either a 25% or a 100% chance of increasing per level. The thing is, these chances *change every level for every class*, which I suppose is the reason why that site portrays the stat growth information the way that it does.

The only stat that has a set growth is HP, which usually increases by vitality/4. On certain designated levels, HP will additionally increase by 20-25 points on top of the vitality-based growth, which I will call a "strong" HP growth in my table below.

Addressing your example specifically, here are the stat growths for each level for the Fighter class:

```
Strong HP growth:
 2-11: yes
12-23: no, yes, yes, repeat
24-50: no, no, yes, repeat

STR:
 2-50: 100%

AGI:
 2-20: 100%
21-29: 25%, 100%, 100%, repeat
30-50: 25%, 100%, repeat

INT:
 2-43: 25%, 25%, 100%, repeat
44-50: 25%

VIT:
 2-31: 100%, 100%, 25%, repeat
32-41: 100%, 25%, repeat
42-50: 25%

LUK:
 2-31: 25%, 100%, 100%, repeat
32-39: 25%, 100%, repeat
40-50: 25%
```

As you can see, the Fighter will gain strength every level, but other stats have "loops" of percentages that they will increase by.

Source: https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/nes/522595-final-fantasy/faqs/57009

Comment: So, if you have between 2 and 50 strength, you have a 100% chance of increasing by one?

Comment: No, at level 2, you have a 100% chance of getting +1 str, and same thing and levels 3, 4, etc.

Comment: Oh. So the numbers on the left are levels?

Comment: Yeah, I edited my answer to hopefully make that more clear.

Comment: So for agility, at level 21 you have a 25% chance, 22 100%, 23 100%, 24 25%, and so on until you hit 29?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. There's a giant table in the FAQ that I linked to that has this breakdown for every class if you'd like to see that.

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I needed :)

Comment: One more thing. What section of the link did you get the info from?

Comment: The giant chart is in the [GROW] section, ie: III part C.

Comment: This system is also in place for Final Fantasy 4 (2 in US, with Cecil). If you used an emulator, you can save scum to optimize/maximum the state growth and create ridiculously OP units.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the correct formula for HP growth is actually `VIT/4 + 1`, not just `VIT/4`. I know `VIT/4` is what AstralEsper's guide says, but the guide seems to be in error here; I checked a disassembly of the game, and FF Hackster for good measure.